# Notes - iCloud.com vs me.com

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I am having a problem seeing all of my notes between my devices. Unfortunately, my primary iCloud account is @me.com. When my newer computer was set up, it was set up with @iCloud.com since @me.com is no longer around. I have the iCloud account as an alias and it works for everything but Notes. I can't figure out how to change my Notes on the Mac to integrate into my mobile devices. If I could just Airdrop, I could at least have the critical ones come through. Any advice?

Comment: me.com is still around... so is mac.com if you owned one of those addresses way back when

Comment: on the left of your notes app do you have option to use your iCloud or your computer?

Comment: On my Mac side, all of my Notes are under iCloud saved to the iCloud drive with the iCloud.com On my iPad & iPhone, the Notes are saved to iCloud with the me.com address. The iCloud.com is listed as an Alias under the me.com (primary) account. In Notes on the Mac, I do not have Notes>Preferences with a box for enable the On My Mac Account. All I really want to know is why, if they are all saved to iCloud with both extensions on the account, they are not syncing. iPhone & iPad sync together but neither with the Mac.

Comment: I do not have a "On the Mac" account because I do not have a Preferences in Notes. I have an account that is on that is "On My Mac" but it is empty. I have "iCloud", "sbcglobal.net", "Yahoo!" and "On My Mac" under Folder list.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tetsujin said, iCloud.com, me.com and mac.com are all the same, the latter two are alias' of iCloud.

In Notes on the mac select View > Show Folders. You should now see where your notes are being saved and will have a heading for "iCloud" and "On my Mac". If you don't see "On my Mac". Select from the menubar Notes > Preferences and check the box "Enable the On My Mac Account".

You can now drag notes from the list in the middle to the groups on the left.